# if specifc line contains substring then output other substrings

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to look for a string on every line of a file and if it exists, return a different specific string.

This post has been edited after solutions were posted, to help better state the question (and therefore some of the earlier responses no longer apply)

I have this code:

```bsh
Numlines=$(grep "" -c File.txt)
for (( line=1; line<=$Numlines; line++ )) ; do 
awk -v line="$line" 'NR==line ...???
```

The string I am looking for is `style-name="T`. If that string is in a line in the for loop, return the digits that are directly after the `T`. The lines in `File.txt` may contain strings like `style-name="T2"`, in which case I want to return just the `2`. The string is not located in the same place on every line in `File.txt`, so I don't think I can use field designations in `awk`.

IIRC, `"/style-name\=\"T/"` should provide the match, but if I use that in my code, it either gives me an error or returns nothing. Maybe the script would check to see if it could produce a match and, if so, use a second line of code to to get the string, although I think that `awk` can accomplish it with a single line of code, once the precursor code is figured out.

Here is a sample of `File.txt`:

```html
<TEST1>     <text:p text:style-name="P4">Hello<text:span text:style-name="T2">world</text:span></text:p>
<tyi.ggg>     <text:p text:style-name="P9">Hi<text:span text:style-name="T16">there</text:span></text:p>
<TEST2>     <text:p text:style-name="P540">0 <text:s/>oooh yeah<text:s text:c="2"/>kool-aid<text:s text:c="12"/>0:00</text:p>
```

The output for the first line (first time through the `for` loop) should be 2. The output for the second line (second time through the `for` loop) should be 16. The output for the third line should be nothing.

Comment: What value does processing the file line-by-line using an external shell loop add? Do you really want to read the whole file `Numlines` times?

Comment: @steeldriver I need to know which line designations have what TEST# and what T# because I am using the TEST# and T# to lookup the appropriate line in another file which has a new T# which I need to bring into File.txt to replace this T# with.  Many of the lines in File.txt will have T# that need to be replaced with new T#s and many wont

Comment: So why not just **output** the values of `NR` and/or `TEST#` alongside the `T#` matches?

Comment: That is effectively what I was trying to do.  I have the line# and NR I was having trouble with the syntax, where awk includes a variable and NR, after I placed the match syntax. While trying to figure things out, I wrote a check to see if there were T#s in the line but my code produced no output. ```T_check=$(awk -v line="$line" 'NR==line "/style-name\=\"T/"' File.txt)``` .  I tried to match to just a word, which also didn't work.: ```T_check=$(awk -v line="$line" 'NR==line "/word/"' File.txt)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the following text as sample (modified the sample provided by the OP):

```html
<TEST1>     <text:p text:style-name="P4">Hello<text:span text:style-name="T2">world</text:span><text:span text:style-name="T3"></text:p>
<TEST2>     <text:p text:style-name="P540">0 <text:s/>oooh yeah<text:s text:c="2"/>kool-aid<text:s text:c="12"/>0:00</text:p>
<ANOTHER_TEST15>     <text:p text:style-name="P9">Hi<text:span text:style-name="T16">there</text:span></text:p>
```

I came up with this combination of `grep` and `sed` commands, which might not be the most efficient, but is relatively simple to understand:

```bsh
grep -n 'style-name="T' File.txt | grep -P -o '^\d+:<\w*>|style-name="T\d+' | sed -z 's/style-name="//g; s/:/ /; s/\nT/ T/g'
```

Breaking down the command:

- `grep -n 'style-name="T' File.txt` adds the line numbers for which `style-name="T` was matched.

  The output is:

  ```
  1:<TEST1>     <text:p text:style-name="P4">Hello<text:span text:style-name="T2">world</text:span><text:span text:style-name="T3"></text:p>
  3:<ANOTHER_TEST15>     <text:p text:style-name="P9">Hi<text:span text:style-name="T16">there</text:span></text:p>
  ```
- `grep -P -o '^\d+:<\w*>|style-name="T\d+'` uses the previous output as input and matches the line numbers with the text inside `:<` and `>` right next to them and `style-name="T` with the number right next to it. Each matching is printed in a new line.

  The output is:

  ```
  1:<TEST1>
  style-name="T2
  style-name="T3
  3:<ANOTHER_TEST15>
  style-name="T16
  ```
- `sed -z 's/style-name="//g; s/:/ /; s/\nT/ T/g'` uses the previous output as input and removes `style-name="` and `:` and replaces the linebreaks before `T` (`\nT`)with a single space followed by `T` ( `T`).

  The output is:

  ```
  1 <TEST1> T2 T3
  3 <ANOTHER_TEST15> T16
  ```

Comment: Hmm, I guess maybe I don't need to know the line numbers necessarily (please see my comment to steeldriver, above). I tried your first suggestion and my latest File.txt has 3 lines, one of them has multiple T#s and I need to get all of them and one of the lines has no matches. out.txt has 6 lines with 2 of them populated. I think I am going to need to know what lines are associated with what data because I am using the matches to lookup data in another file and reassign T#s

Comment: ...out.txt has 6 lines with 2 of them populated *with only 1 T#

Comment: @BeastOfCaebannog That approach is new to me and I like it. Matching on "TEST" won't work because the text there is not always the same, but capturing field $1 should do it.  I also need to capture all T#s when there is more than one (maybe it would have been better if I edited my initial post instead of putting that information in a comment, later, as I did).  I think your solution can work for me, if i can figure out how to extract the 1st field and also all T#s.

Comment: @Insideup Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Its working!  Thank you! I had to make some tweaks for my particular case where there was a space I had accidentally inserted in file.txt and also I didn't think to include that there would be a period in the <TEST#>, which appears to be solved with adding ```.\w*``` in the (inlc the edit)  ```grep -P -o '^\d+:<\w*.\w*>|style-name="T\d+'```

Comment: @Insideup Good to know that this was helpful to you! I would recommend that you also adjust your question properly to better state the problem, so it can also be helpful to other people. Also make sure that you escape the dot you added using a backslash (\\) right before it, since the `grep` command uses regex and `.` means "just one character" and not a literal dot!

Comment: Whoops. Thanks for that final correction. I've made edits to my post to help the next people.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any value in processing the file multiple times using a shell loop.

In GNU awk, you can capture sub-patterns into an array with the `match` function. So you could simply do:

```
gawk 'match($0,/style-name="T([0-9]+)"/,m){print m[1]}' File.txt
```

In regular POSIX awk, the `match` function doesn't have this extended functionality, but you could instead use its `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` to extract the desired substring:

```
awk 'match($0,/style-name="T[0-9]+"/){print substr($0,RSTART+13,RLENGTH-14)}' File.txt
```

[If you *must* do it in a shell loop targeting a particular line number at each iteration for some unspecified reason, then you can change the rule to `NR==line && match(...) {...}`].

---

If you need to extract *multiple* `T#` values per record, you can wrap the `match` in a loop that chomps through `$0` ex:

```
gawk '
  {test=$1}       # save the `TEST#` before we start the `match` loop 
  {
    T=""
    while(match($0,/style-name="T([0-9]+)"/,m)) {
      T = T=="" ? m[1] : T OFS m[1]     # append the `T#`
      $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)    # remove the part we already matched
    }
  } 
  T !="" {
    print NR,test,T    # print the record (line) number, `TEST#`, and accumulated `T#`s
  }
' File.txt
1 <TEST1> 2
2 <TEST2> 16
```

To do the same thing in non-GNU awk using the `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` method that I showed previously, replace the `while` loop with:

```
while(match($0,/style-name="T[0-9]+"/)) {
  t = substr($0,RSTART+13,RLENGTH-14)
  T = T=="" ? t : T OFS t
  $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)    # remove the part we already matched
}
```

Comment: In my simple-so-I-can-figure-it-out example File.txt that I made for myself, there was only one T# per line, but IRL a line can have a number of them, In the end I want to have a file with : line #, TEST#, T# T# T#....

Comment: @Insideup please see edited answer

Comment: I have awk but not gawk (I thought they were the same on Ubuntu??)  I am getting syntax errors: ```awk: line 5: syntax error at or near ,``` and ```awk: line 9: syntax error at or near }```.

Comment: Based on those error messages, it looks like your `awk` is actually provided by `mawk` (which has more limited functionality than `gawk`). You should be able to install `gawk` from the Ubuntu repository.

Comment: I found awk-nsantos GNU awk. I have some reservations to install, which maybe someone can assuage?  If it were to replace the awk functionality that I am using in other scripts and produce undesirable results (expect probably not, but I don't have the expertise to judge), I would tend to assume it was something I did and spend hours trying to fix.

Comment: @Insideup if you can't install gawk from the Ubuntu repository then I suggest sticking with mawk - I've added a version of the final code that doesn't rely on the `match` function's GNU extensions

Comment: That works.  Thank you.